# Google App Engine - webapp2 - routes - not reading my url - what's wrong?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From my HTML template - I'm generating a URL to submit to from the form to below:

```
localhost:8080/AD/institution/?institName=Poal+Instit&submit=Add+New
```

However, my URL routing page has regex to capture the URL above - but it's not - any ideas on why my regex is incorrect to read the above URL?

```
(r'/institName=<instit_new:[a-zA-Z&=+]+>', handler='xyz')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` part of the url (anything after the ?) is not matched by routes.

Comment: oh bummer. Thanks for the info - this saves me lots of time trying to make it work

Comment: In webob/request.py request.path (matched against by webapp2) it reads: The path of the request, without host or query string

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you showed your actual code.  My guess is that your regexp needs to show:

```
r'/AD/institution/.*'
```